# parse date form string in bigquery

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery

I have a table in bigquery that has a column name "timeStamp" with data type of STRING. The value in this column looks like this "20180902".

This is how I am trying to parse this string to date

```
SELECT PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', timeStamp) AS date FROM data.data_temp
```

But this throws an error that says "Failed to parse input string "timeStamp""

Also, at the same time the following query works successfully and returns the date as "2018-09-02"

```
SELECT PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', '20180902') AS date FROM data.data_temp
```

Any clues on what is going on here and how to solve this?

Comment: I found the issue. My table had a row at the bottom that had the value "timeStamp" . Deleted that row and everything worked .

Comment: . . You should delete the question or accept Mikhail's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below example shows that if value is really "20180902" as you state it should work

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '20180902' timeStamp   
)
SELECT 
  `timeStamp`, 
  PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', timeStamp    ) AS date    
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result as

```
Row   timeStamp   date   
1     20180902    2018-09-02
```

so the issue potentially in some wrong value in some rows  - and you need to identify these row(s)

Comment: Yes . I found the issue. Posted above.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. My table had a row at the bottom that had the value "timeStamp" . Deleted that row and everything worked .